# Ceph did not deploy to machine 0 why?

Tags: juju, ceph

Love juju and this ceph charms is great.  Can you help with this issue ...

I have deployed the ceph charm to a MAAS cluster of 3 nodes (machine: 0, 1, & 2)

I used this command to deploy:

```
juju deploy --config ./ceph.yaml -n 3 ceph
```

Now when I check the juju status I see that ceph has gone to machine: 1, 2, & 3.  Since I don't have a machine 3 it is pending.

How can I get it to deploy to the 3 node I already have ?

Here is my juju status...

```
juju status
2013-11-11 20:46:51,893 INFO Connecting to environment...
2013-11-11 20:46:52,563 INFO Connected to environment.
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: 8ypjm.ceph
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-d8686094-48c9-11e3-b313-deadbeeefb1a/
    instance-state: unknown
  1:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: a8nke.ceph
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-88a58b34-48cb-11e3-9d7d-deadbeeefb1a/
    instance-state: unknown
  2:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: f7fby.ceph
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-c7d89b0c-48cb-11e3-b313-deadbeeefb1a/
    instance-state: unknown
  3:
    instance-id: pending
services:
  ceph:
    charm: cs:precise/ceph-16
    relations:
      mon:
      - ceph
    units:
      ceph/0:
        agent-state: start-error
        machine: 1
        public-address: a8nke.ceph
      ceph/1:
        agent-state: start-error
        machine: 2
        public-address: f7fby.ceph
      ceph/2:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: 3
        public-address: null
2013-11-11 20:46:52,999 INFO 'status' command finished successfully
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to place units on machines, you need to use the placement directive --to.

You can't use this when specifying number of units however.

So you'd have to go:

```
juju deploy --config ./ceph.yaml ceph --to 0
juju add-unit ceph --to 1
juju add-unit ceph --to 2
```

This is assuming that you already having machines 0, 1 and 2 in existence.

Comment: agent-state: start-error is also bad - this would indicate misconfiguration of the deployed charm against the server - please check the fs-uuid and mon-secret's have been supplied and that the block devices you are trying to use on the server exist.

Comment: That is great.Thanks for the pointers on deployment. I have deployed a 4th node (machine 3) and now have 3 agents in start-error.  I think this is a separate topic so I'll close this one, do some testing and research and open another if required.

Comment: Looks like my issue was DNS related. The celerybeat job that sync dhcpd.leases into the zone file does not seem to be working on my system.  I manually added the address lines into the zone file /etc/bind/maas/zone.ceph then restarted named.  Used juju to destroy-service ceph then deployed it again and this time it all worked.

Comment: I have tested this answer and it didn't work for me: $ juju deploy --config ./ceph.yaml ceph --to 0 gave me an error "juju: error: unrecognized arguments: --to 0"

Comment: machine 0 is the zookeeper.  As of Nov 2013 juju 0.5+bzr531-0ubuntu1.3 is the current juju package in the Ubuntu archive.  This version does not support the option --to.  It won't let you deploy any charms to the zookeeper.